# Using where clause in datatable-serverside sql search not working

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

In data table server side i need to display the records whose status is Approval. Query works fine. But search doesn't work. If is use where clause in the query search doesn't work. Can anyone help me out in this. Here is the code.

**Index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Datatable with mysql</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="font-awesome-style-css" href="http://phpflow.com/code/css/bootstrap3.min.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="">
            <h1>Rank Holders</h1>
            <div class="">
                <table id="employee_grid" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>year of Passing</th>
                            <th>email</th>
                            <th>Date of Birth</th>
                            <th>Company Name</th>
                            <th>Designation</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document)
        .ready(function () {
            $('#employee_grid')
                .DataTable({
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        url: "response.php", // json datasource
                        type: "post", // type of method  ,GET/POST/DELETE
                        error: function () {
                            $("#employee_grid_processing")
                                .css("display", "none");
                        }
                    }
                });
        });

    </script>
```

**Response.php**

```
 <?php
    //include connection file 
    include_once("connection.php");

    // initilize all variable
    $params = $columns = $totalRecords = $data = array();

    $params = $_REQUEST;

    //define index of column
    $columns = array( 
        0 =>'id',
        1 =>'name', 
        2 =>'yop',
        3 => 'email1',
        4 => 'dob1',
        5 =>'company',

        6 =>'designation'

    );

    $where = $sqlTot = $sqlRec = "";

    // check search value exist
    if( !empty($params['search']['value']) ) {   
        $where .=" WHERE ";
        $where .=" (name LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' "; 

        $where .=" OR yop LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";
        $where .=" OR email1 LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";
        $where .=" OR dob1 LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";
        $where .=" OR company LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";

        $where .=" OR designation LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' )";
                $where .=" OR status LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' )";
    }

    // getting total number records without any search
    $sql = "SELECT id,name,yop,email1,dob1,company,designation FROM `alumni` where status='Approval'";

    $sqlTot .= $sql;
    $sqlRec .= $sql;

    //concatenate search sql if value exist
    if(isset($where) && $where != '') {

        $sqlTot .= $where;
        $sqlRec .= $where;
    }


    $sqlRec .=  " ORDER BY ". $columns[$params['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$params['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$params['start']." ,".$params['length']." ";

    $queryTot = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlTot) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));


    $totalRecords = mysqli_num_rows($queryTot);

    $queryRecords = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch rank holders");

    //iterate on results row and create new index array of data
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($queryRecords) ) { 
    $data[] = $row;

       }


    $json_data = array(
            "draw"            => intval( $params['draw'] ),   
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalRecords ),  
            "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalRecords),
            "data"            => $data   // total data array
            );

    echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format
?>
```

Comment: mysql or SQL-Server?

Comment: Learn about prepared statements

Comment: Do you get any error message or what means `not working`?

Comment: `echo $sqlRec;` and what do you see?

Comment: Both `$sqlRec` and `$sqlTot` have `where` two times, first is from end of `$sql` and second is from `$where`

Comment: Query works fine I get the data whose staatus is Approval but search is not working

Comment: @user6582683 neither `$sqlRec` nor `$sqlTot` will work because they are incorrect as I said.

Comment: So what I need to do to make it work

Comment: @user6582683 Add `echo $sqlRec; exit;` to the line right below ` $sqlRec .= $where;`.  Then navigate directly to `response.php` in your browser.  You should see what you've put together there, and the problem will probably be obvious to you.